Electric Field Within a Conductor
I was reading Purcell’s text on electrodynamics when I read his argument that in the absence of external forces, there cannot be any electric fields within a conductor for the static situation. My question is, why must it ever reach the static situation? What’s to say that the charges within the conductor do not continuously move around?

The electrons do continuously move around. But it’s random thermal motion

Let's split the answer here, first treating the link between the micro- and macroscopic description of the physics, then showing that there is no current and no electric field in a conductor using a macroscopic description of the problem, relying on Maxwell's equations.
Micro- and macroscopic description
Statistics in general, and expected values (or averaging) in particular, provides the link between the microscopic and macroscopic descriptions. As an example, in the point of space $\mathbf{r}$, or better, in an elementary volume $\Delta V(\mathbf{r})$ centered in $\mathbf{r}$

charge density $\rho(\mathbf{r},t)$ is defined so that
$$\rho(\mathbf{r},t) \Delta V(\mathbf{r}) \sim q \, \langle n \rangle (\mathbf{r},t) \ ,$$
being $q$ the charge of a discrete (identical here, to avoid useless complications) particle, and $\langle n \rangle (\mathbf{r},t)$ the average number of particles in $\Delta V$
electric current density $\mathbf{j}(\mathbf{r},t)$ is defined so that
$$\mathbf{j}(\mathbf{r},t) \Delta V(\mathbf{r}) \sim q \langle n \mathbf{v} \rangle(\mathbf{r},t) \sim q \ \langle n \rangle (\mathbf{r},t) \ \langle \mathbf{v} \rangle (\mathbf{r},t) \ ,$$
assuming un-correlated fluctuation of $n$ and $\mathbf{v}$. As you can see, if the average velocity (it's a vector!) is zero there is no "macroscopic" current. Without external forcing and in a homogeneous isotropic medium, it's reasonable to expect a "spherical symmetric" distribution of the velocity providing $\langle \mathbf{v} \rangle = \mathbf{0}$: microscopic particles move with non-zero velocity distributed according to that spherically symmetric distribution, but the average velocity is zero.

No charges, no current, zero electric field in a conductor, after a short transient
Relying on the Maxwell's equations, charge continuity, and the Ohm's law of a linear isotropic non-dispersive media, it's possible to prove that an initial non-zero charge distribution exponentially goes to zero with a very small time constant.
The local form of Ohm's law reads
$$\mathbf{e}(\mathbf{r},t) = \rho_R \mathbf{j}(\mathbf{r},t) \qquad \text{or} \qquad \mathbf{j}(\mathbf{r},t) = \sigma \mathbf{e}(\mathbf{r},t) \ ,$$
being $\mathbf{e}(\mathbf{r},t)$ the electricl field, $\mathbf{j}(\mathbf{r},t)$ the current density in $\mathbf{r}$ at time $t$, $\rho_R$ the resistivity, and $\sigma = \rho_R^{-1}$ the conductivity of the medium.
A differential solution can be derived for the electric charge density, plugging Ohm's law and Gauss' law for the electric field in continuity equation for electric charge,
$$\begin{aligned}
0 & = \partial_t \rho + \nabla \cdot \mathbf{j} = \\
& = \partial_t \rho + \sigma \nabla \cdot \mathbf{e} = \\
& = \partial_t \rho + \frac{\sigma}{\varepsilon} \rho \ ,
\end{aligned}$$
whose solution reads
$$\rho(\mathbf{r},t) = \rho(\mathbf{r},0) \exp\left[ -\frac{\sigma}{\varepsilon} t \right] \ ,$$
being $\rho(\mathbf{r},0)$ the initial charge density distribution.
The time constant of the exponential decay is $\tau = \frac{\varepsilon}{\sigma}$. For a conductor, $\varepsilon \sim \varepsilon_0 = 8.85 \cdot 10^{-12} \, F \, m^{-1}$, $\sigma \sim 10^{7} \frac{1}{\Omega \, m}$
$$\tau = \frac{\varepsilon}{\sigma} \sim \frac{10^{-11} \, F \, m^{-1}}{10^7 \frac{1}{\Omega \, m}} \sim 10^{-18} s \ ,$$
i.e. after a very short time interval, charge density insiede a conductor (and thus electric current and electric field, since $\mathbf{e} \propto \mathbf{j}$) is approximately zero.

Electrons are free to move within a conductor (conductors have a sea of electrons). Due to electrostatic repulsion and this freedom of movement, electrons push each other until they reach the surface of the conductor. This motion continues until all electrons are as far apart from each other as possible, minimizing repulsion.
If any electron were to move, it would cause other electrons to move in response to counteract that motion, quickly restoring equilibrium. Thus, the charges arrange themselves in a configuration where Coulomb forces are balanced, resulting in no net electric field (electric field is force per charge) within the conductor in the static equilibrium state. For any electron on the surface, there is an electron on the opposite face exerting an equal and opposite force, maintaining equilibrium.

There can be no macroscopic static electric field in a insulated conductor. At microscopic scale the fields of nuclei and electrons and for example optical phonons will be there as the screening by the conduction electrons is imperfect.
Obviously, this is a linear approximation. If an external electrostatic field is strong enough things will break down.
If the conductor is not insulated and there is a current, then there in general there is a field, as $j=\sigma E$. Also there can be transient effects if the electrostatic approximation does not strictly hold.
